# Selecting Multiple Select Element Options On The Fly In HTA using VBS

Tags: vbscript, hta

I'm looking for a vbs solution to enhance a select multiple element that reads the options from a computers.txt file with radio buttons or buttons that do various selections:

```
- select all 
- select none 
- select workstations 
- select laptops 
- select server 
- select workstations+laptops
```

With that in mind I had to use a text file from which the computers are being read to something like this(IP/COMPUTER NAME/MAC ADDRESS/ROLE):

```
IP - value of select options
PC NAME - text of select options
MAC ADDRESS - for usage by subroutine
ROLE - to be used for selection


192.168.0.1,PC01,00-18-F4-6C-10-BB,server 
192.168.0.2,PC02,00-18-F2-6C-10-BC,laptop 
192.168.0.3,PC03,00-18-F5-6C-10-BD,workstation 
192.168.0.4,PC04,00-18-F1-6C-10-BE,workstation 
192.168.0.5,PC05,00-18-F1-6C-10-BF,laptop 
192.168.0.6,PC06,00-18-F1-6C-10-BG,workstation
```

What would be the best approach to achieve these types of selections?

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider ADO : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974559.aspx

The Jet database may also suit. It is often installed with the windows system, the exceptions being the 64 bit versions, and very early versions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that option.I do use this on windows 7 64 bit machines. I don't think this is a really issue, but I'm looking for an example how to read a comma delimited file store this into an array , create select options with values from first column, text from the second and how do I select from this select multiple element when I press a button all workstations for example.

Comment: With ADO (as per the link), you can read the comma delimited text file into a recordset and use a where statement or filter to return the records you want. Furthermore, you can use getrows to return an array, but I see no reason why you would want an array, when a recordset is ideal. I am not sure why you do not wish to do this.